# Disable pinch to zoom on Opera browser

Tags: browser, touchpad, opera, zoom

I know how to disable pinch-to-zoom on my trackpad for Windows 10. However I don't want this. I would like to disable this only for Opera (or Chrome if Opera can't).

To clarify: Is there a way to disable pinch to zoom on Opera?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there is a way to disable it specifically for Chrome. Wish I could help with Opera. Chrome really should step it up and put these options in.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable the pinch-to-zoom gesture on my computer by disabling it using the touch pad driver software.

**Note:** You can [disable mouse gestures](http://www.opera.com/help/tutorials/gestures/) in Opera, but it **won't** disable pinch-to-zoom. It seems that gesture is rather controlled by the mouse driver.

> To enable or disable mouse gestures, select Settings > Preferences > Advanced > Shortcuts, and check or uncheck “Enable mouse gestures”.